# How to center the view when I zoom it

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

When I touch a UIScrollView, I zoom the view to a large scale. But the view is not centered to the place where I have touched. I want to know how to make the view center when I touch it, can someone give me some example code.

Or if the scrollview have had the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before zooming, set the scrollview's contentoffset so the point you touched to be in the center.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to make the point where I touched center not the whole view.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Save the point you have touched and set the contentOffset to match that point, them make the zoom. it will zoom and the point touch will be in the middle of the scrollview's frame

Comment: set the scrollview's contentoffset ? I do not totally understand. Can you show me some simple code?

Comment: when you scroll by finger, the content offset of the scroll is changed. If you want to scroll programmatically, you say; [myScrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(233, 129)]; It was an example. Instead of CGPointMake(233, 129), use the point you have got after the touch

Comment: well you will have to play a little with that point's values: add 1/2 of scroll width to x and 1/2 of scroll height to y